# when should we declare destructor as =delete in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

i have known that a destructor which is declared as **delete** could not used as

```
A a;
```

but could be used as

```
A*a =new a();
```

but we could not free the memory by using

```
delete a;
```

so when is it recommended or prefered to declare a destructor as deleted?Is there an idiom?

Comment: Possibly for "static" class (with only static members).

Comment: In the "old days" you would mark new and delete as private if you only wanted the object to work as a member or on the stack.=delete gives the same behaviour in a more logical way.

Comment: @Slava Ooh nice :)

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't say that it is recommended or preferred in any real production code.

But you can imagine an example when you want to ensure an object cannot be normally deleted; one example might be a global memory manager object or other singleton intended to outlive main. Object without destructor just cannot be deleted.

I think there are better to achieve that, like encapsulation / hiding.